# Nvim-cmp not working from neovim start-up

Tags: lua, neovim

I have upgraded to neovim 0.7.0 but I am experiencing some odd issues with nvim-cmp

I have cmp.lua file that starts with

```
local cmp_status_ok, cmp = pcall(require, "cmp")
if not cmp_status_ok then
  return
end
```

and then the settings from the nvim-cmp page. My init.lua is:

```
require "user.options"
require "user.keymaps"
require "user.plugins"
require "user.colorscheme"
require "user.cmp"
require "user.lsp"
require "user.telescope"
require "user.treesitter"
require "user.autopairs"
require "user.comment"
```

If I start neovim normally, autocompletion does not work. If I run

```
:luafile %
```

in cmd.lua autocompletion works perfect in that neovim session. So, it does not seem to be an issue with the set-up file. Could it be that the cmp.lua file is invalidated later on??

Any suggestions are welcome.

Comment: Do you have `cmp.lua` placed inside the `/lua/user/` folder?

Comment: Yes, all the these files are in /lua/user/

Comment: Maybe cmp is not avaiable at startup somehow. You know  basic debugging? Add some print statements to debug what has happened in your `cmp.lua` file.